# For Android,will the unused class files in jar be (or not be) included in .apk?

Tags: android, android-library, apk

For Android,will the unused class files in jar be (or not be) included in .apk?

For example, there is a library in the form of the jar file. I may only use some of the files. I am just wondering what the .apk will include.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the unused files will be still included in apk.

But if you enabled [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html), they will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The APK will include unused class files.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Ivan's answer: You can configure ProGuard to keep certain classes it would otherwise remove (for example, because they are only referenced by reflection) by adding lines like this to proguard-project.txt:

```
# single class
-keep class com.example.reflected.MyClass
# whole package
-keep class com.example.reflected.*
```